# Стиль для input и button

Tags: html, css

К примеру, у нас есть кнопка и мы задали ей стиль с фоновой картинкой. Тогда если у блока, в котором эта кнопка, при наведении изменить цвет, то хоть даже если картинка с прозрачным фоном png, то он остается прежним. Но если тот же стиль придать просто ссылке, то ее фон поменяется.

[image]

Comment: Код выложите

Comment: просто кнопке дан класс 
<button class="123"></button>
а классу дано background-image: картинка с прозрачным фоном. Если тоже самое сделать с ссылкой то все норм
<a class="123"></a>

Comment: в опере нормально работает. в хроме кнопка непрозрачная получается...
наверное, надо менять фон и кнопке тоже чтоб работало как надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

чтобы корректно отображалось фоновый рисунок надо задавать так:

```
  background: url("img.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

либо, если удобней:

```
background-color:transparent;
background-image: url('img.png');
```

ибо не только сама картинка должна иметь прозрачный фон, но и элемент содержащий её